# Processing html tags inside xml with fop

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I've got an object that's being converted into SAXSource and then converted into a PDF with FOP. Some of the data however is in HTML format inside the XML tags. I'd like to have this these HTML tags parsed as actual elements by the stylesheet, which would mean reading it in its unescaped format, but I can't figure out how to do this. I have `disable-output-escaping` set in the stylesheet, but I think the data in the XML has already been parsed as "escaped" before it gets to the stylesheet and processed.

Here's the code for converting.

```
FOUserAgent foUserAgent = getUserAgent();
PDFRenderer pdfrenderer = new PDFRenderer(); 

pdfrenderer.setUserAgent(foUserAgent); 
foUserAgent.setRendererOverride(pdfrenderer);

URIResolver resolver = myWebContext.getResolver();
foUserAgent.setURIResolver(resolver);

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
byte[] b = null;

try {
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(); 
//transformer.setOutputProperty("disable-output-escaping", "yes");
// kicks back error --- invalid property

Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, foUserAgent, out); 
Source xsl = resolver.resolve(xslFilename, null);
transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsl); 
res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler()); 
transformer.transform(xmlSrc, res); 
b = out.toByteArray();
```

Comment: You need to post a small sample of the xml file and the relevant xslt snippet. You only provided the java.

Comment: I think you need to use cop-of in your xslt to keep these tag as it is.